# We are unable to spy the Table using object spy of test complete,

Tags: testcomplete

We are automating a desktop application `(ININ)` using Test complete. We are unable to spy  the table  using  object spy of test complete. However while recording we are able to click that  row, but we need entire text of that row. Even in the object spy properties we couldn’t able to find the properties of this row.

**Element:**

`Aliases.InteractionDesktop.HwndSource_CafeShellWindow.WinFormsAdapter.WinFormsHostPanel.MyInteractionsQueueControl.QueueListView2`

Table element and Row screenshot. We tried using  following  methods to get the text of that Row but we got null data.

```
   GetSubItemRect_2
   GetSubItemAt
   get_Items 
   get_SelectedItem
   get_Text
   get_WindowText
   GetColumns and tried `enter code here`to get column text.
   GetItemAtenter code here
   GetSubItemRect
   Items.Item_2
   Items.Item
   Items.get_InnerList
   Items.get_Item_2
   Items.get_Item
```

Answer (score 0):

First your application should be an Open application as described [Hear](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/open-apps/index.html) 
(ININ is a product name I suppose) and TestComplete should be supports technology [mention hear](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/desktop/index.html) of the application.

test complete supports most of table grids ...[the link](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/specific-tasks/grids/index.html)

Also If you posted code while recording can be help more..

The best place to get exact answer is [Test Complete forum](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete/ct-p/TestComplete_forum)